# How do I declare a custom compare function inside a class?

Tags: c++

When I define the custom comparison function inside the class I'll get the error:

> 'Solution::myfunction': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

But if I define it outside the class it works. How can I define it **inside** the class?

```
class Solution {
    public:
    bool myfunction(const vector<int> &i, const vector<int> &j) { 
        return i.front() < j.front()); 
    }
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    ...
    sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), myfunction);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It needs to be `static` to work like that.

Comment: Non-member functions *decay* to pointers to themselves, as does `static` member functions. Non-static member functions do *not* decay to pointers automatically, you have to use the address-of operator `&` explicitly to get a pointer (just as the error message tells you).

Comment: Missing declaration of `vec` may hide another problem with your code. I assumed: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;`.

Answer (score 7):

Non-static member functions take an implicit `this` as first parameter. The correct way to call your member function would be

```
Solution s;
std::vector<int> x;
s.myfunction(x,x);
```

when you actually want a function that only takes two vectors as parameter. Declare it as `static` or use a free-function (the prefered way).

PS: Unless you need to call the same comparison function in different scopes, I would suggest to use a lambda:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [](const vector<int> &i, const vector<int> &j) { 
                return  i.front()<j.front(); 
        }
     );
```

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot would be my first choice too, for some reason I assumed OP needs the comparison in different places, will edit the answer

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `rbegin` and `rend` instead of `begin` and `end`?

Comment: @skpro19 no. Chances are that I didnt even notice when writing the answer and just used what OP had used without changing more than necessary

Comment: Okay. Also, does the above trick work if the size of the container being sorted is less than 2?

Comment: @skpro19 what "trick" ? I would actually never use `rbegin` and `rend` for `std::sort`. And yes `std::sort` works with any size of the container

Answer (score 2):

There are couple way to fix it:

I prefer provide lambda:

```cpp
sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](const auto &a, const auto &b)
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                            b.begin(), b.end());
    });
```

Other way is to provide comparetion class:

```cpp
class CmpIntVectors {
public:
    bool operator(const vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                            b.begin(), b.end());
    }

};

...

sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), CmpIntVectors{});
```

Or make `myfunction` static.

**Disclaimer**: I'm assuming that your `vec` looks like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are the preferred way nowadays instead of defining your own comparison function. They are more readable and *in-place*, i.e. you can see the code where you call sort() rather than look in some header file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you still want to use class member function, then use lambda and pass `this` to it:

```
sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [this](const vector<int> &i, const vector<int> &j){
  return this->myfunction(i, j);
});
```